# Remove items in key value pairs and place in array?

Tags: jquery, python, arrays

I'm having trouble getting a basic Array of id numbers sent to the server.

Finally I am at least able to get all the values over.

---

jQuery:

```
var params = {}

for(var i =0; i<contacts.length; i++){
    params[i] = contacts[i];
}
```

Params will hold 2 id numbers:
`Object {0: 5000209, 1: 5000186}` < I just wanted to send over the id numbers, but for now have to send this key value pairs.

---

In Python (Pyramid)

`contacts = self.body`

^ This will be: `contacts = {dict}{'1': '5000186', '0': '5000209'}`

**My question is how do I now get the id numbers out of that dict and into a basic array in Python?**

Comment: `[contacts["0"], contacts["1"]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
arr = contacts.values()
```

Comment: Thank you! Note that dictionaries in python are unsorted, if you need the list in a certain order, you will need to modify this a bit: `arr=[value for (key,value) in sorted(contacts.iteritems())]`

Answer (score 1):

```
foo_dict = []    
for key,value in contacts.iteritems():
     foo_dict.append(value)
```

with this code you will get `contacts = [5000186, 5000209]`

Comment: actually, what I'm trying to get is this `contacts = [5000186, 5000209]`

Comment: using dict as a variable name and worse again using it on  a list